# Getting rid of the Figure 1 : bit

Tags: latex

In my Latex document I have a number of figures with Captions like the following :

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.35\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{zhangsanfeng.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Zhang Sanfeng}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

This will give me the picture and a caption of **Figure 1 : Zhang Sanfeng**

I want to get rid of the **Figure 1 :** bit.

I have the following :

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{}    
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}
```

This gets rid of the **Figure 1** but does not get rid of the **:** so I am left with **: Zhang Sanfeng**.

How do I get rid of this?

Also, is there any resource available that lists the commands that can be renewed.. I can't find anything anywhere!

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

Will remove the "Figure *n*:" from  your captions.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for subfigures as well?